# Change the glyph of a clicked button on the callback

Tags: reactjs

In `react` I create several rows in a table, some of the rows with a glyph icon like this:

```
var StockRow = React.createClass({
    unwatch: function() {
        this.props.unwatchStockHandler(this.props.stock.symbol);
    },
...
 return (                                     
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.unwatch}>
                <span className={currentGlyph} aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></td>
    ...
```

This works fine. Later, when the user clicks on the button on the browser in a given table-row, the function `this.unwatch` gets called that also works fine. **On the clicked button how do I change the glyph of the button to someOtherGlyph and have it reflected on the browser immediately?**

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {  
    ....
    },
    unwatchStock: function(symbol) {
        //how do I change the glyph of the button that was clicked?
    },
    ....
```

I am used to having the callback having the sender included in the function that gets called like this (although is the sender the webpage,  the table, the row, the button???) :

```
unwatchStock: function(sender, symbol) {
```

and then something like this might work (assuming the sender is the button):

```
sender.buttonIcon = someOtherGlyph
```

If it helps, the button is in the first column of the row. Maybe I need to  inherit a new component from Button, but not sure how to do it:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // What goes in here?
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Post Edit :)**

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    var rows = [];
    for(var i in data){
      rows.push(
        <tr>
          <td><Button/></td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {rows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentGlyph: 'glyph-val-init' };

    this.unwatch = this.unwatch.bind(this);
  }
  unwatch(){
    this.setState({
      currentGlyph: 'new-value'
    })
  }
  render() {
    <div>
      <button className={this.state.currentGlyph} onClick={this.unwatch}></button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

While this code doesn't change the glyph it does show changing the text value which can easily be repurposed for change a class name

Basically what you want to do is have a

```
this.state = {glyph: 'value'}
```

and then later set the state to change the glyph value

```
this.setState({glyph: 'new value'})
```

> excuse the non-jsx format but the editor doesn't allow for that

```js
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currentGlyph: 'glyph val init' };
    
    this.unwatch = this.unwatch.bind(this);
  }
  unwatch(e){
    var target = e.target;
    this.setState({
      currentGlyph: 'new glyph'
    });
  }
  render() {
    return React.createElement('button', { onClick: this.unwatch }, this.state.currentGlyph);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(HomePage), document.getElementById('rroot'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='rroot'>root</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am confused by something, in the table several rows have buttons with their own glyph. If I set the state like you are suggesting, am I not assuming all rows will have the same glyph changed? I just want the button in the row that was clicked changed

Comment: oh, yes you are right. What you could do then is have a child ButtonClass that has it's own state like <td><ButtonClass/></td>

Comment: Please see the original post. Is this what you mean by a "child button" ?

Comment: Ok trying that, but now that the glyph is encapsulated in the class, what becomes of the way  to construct it, i.e., what do I do with <span className={currentGlyph} ? What does the  row creation look like now?

Comment: ^ you make an array of Button React elems if you need to pass data to the Button, you can use props like <Button data={data[i]}/>

Comment: I can't get this to work to save my life. It seems strange that the whole line that does work <td><button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.unwatch}>, [note no <div/>] can be replaced by the stuff in your render function (I don't understand why div is there either)

Comment: If I insert what does work into your render function, that doesn't work either!   render() { <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.unwatch}>
    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    </button> }

Comment: Aha! Forgot to put return(...) in render() !!!!! Now getting somewhere!

Comment: Ha good! You are right - the div doesn't need to be there but with React everything in a JSX element needs to be contained in one element so I put the div there around the button incase you went to put a span or something in there as well, because then you would need one parent element

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JSBin to demonstrate how to do this.

http://jsbin.com/fagegelele/1/edit?js,output

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
    this.toggleChecked = this.toggleChecked.bind(this);
  }

  toggleChecked() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
  }

  render() {
    const checked = this.state.checked ? 'CHECKED' : 'UNCHECKED';
    return (
      <div
        className={checked}
        onClick={this.toggleChecked}
      >
        Checked? {checked}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You keep the flag for the glyph icon in the state and change that when you click the button. In the example in the JSBin, click the text that says "Checked?" to see it working. This would be an example of what you would want to put inside each table cell you want a glyph icon.

edit: Here is a jsbin that pairs the table data with the glyphicon that is needed for that particular table cell:  http://jsbin.com/vopiroz/4/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thanks. That gets me closer. Then I am assuming that say I call my component MyButton the line above reads:  <td><MyButton type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm" onClick={this.unwatch}>
                <span className={currentGlyph} aria-hidden="true"></span>  ?

Comment: It really depends on what your structure is for wanting to unwatch a stock. Is this strictly presentational or do you have something else to do when a button is clicked? If you only want the glyphicon to change it would be: <td><MyButton /></td>

Comment: I didn't understand your comment when I read it, but now I am running into the problem you hinted at. In the Button component, I need to know what the symbol is. In the original code it was just "this.props.stock.symbol" but I don't appear to have access to this inside the button component...

Comment: I ammended the original post to show what I mean by showing the function "unwatch: function()" See that "this.props.stock.symbol"? I don't seem to have access to that inside Button.

Comment: You won't have access to the glyph if you don't pass it down as props. If you need each one of your rows to have a glyph that is tied to some outside state, you actually to keep track of that state. It might be easier to ditch the button idea and keep your row glyph state in an array in the table component. Let me toss together a little bit more on a JSBin.

Comment: Here is an updated JSBin that pairs the glyph with the representation of your table. http://jsbin.com/vopiroz/4/edit?js,console,output. You can click on one of the rows and it will switch it's glyph based on the current glyph.

Comment: Interesting. So now we are encapsulating our own table. I like the idea of a seperation of concerns here and I sort of like the Button idea. One thing, "constructor(props)" code in the Button that then gets "super(props)". Isn't that parameter the "props" from the outside? If not, why not just pass the [needed] props to the button? What the heck is that props?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137252/discussion-between-brandon-roberts-and-ivan).